# Identify a future date for a group of observations

Tags: stata

I have in Stata a dataset in long format (i.e. multiple observations per individual) and I would like to `drop` all the records of  an individual with a start date `V2` after 01/01/2009. How do I go about this? In the example below, I would like to `drop` all the records of `id` 1 since their start date is after 01/01/2009.

[image]

Comment: What's with the **r** tag?

Comment: I have removed the `r` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `v2` is a Stata daily date variable, then you need

```
bysort v1 (v2) : drop if v2[1] > mdy(1, 1, 2009)
```

where `>` embodies after (and if you really mean "on or after" you should use `>=` instead).

If `v2` is a string variable or a numeric variable with value labels, you will need to convert it first.

This follows from standard uses of `by:`. One tutorial is accessible at https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0004